# Order to declare VirtualHost for domain and subdomains, Apache2, Ubuntu

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I declared in my DNS, my `domain`, `subdomain1` and `subdomain2`, and everything works.

Then I create my directories like this :
`/var/www/domain.com/public_html/index.html` `/var/www/subdomain1.domain.com/public_html/index.html` `/var/www/subdomain2.domain.com/public_html/index.html`

Then I create : `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.subdomain1.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.subdomain1.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain1.domain.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.subdomain2.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.subdomain2.domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain2.domain.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I disable the default configuration: `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`

Then I activate each of the websites: `sudo a2ensite domain.conf`

I restart Apache 2: `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`

The problem is that all links point to the first declared VirtualHost, even when I separate the VirtualHost declarations in separate `.conf` files, it will always be the first VirtualHost in the directory that will be opened for all DNS domains.

Comment: In your browser address bar, are you trying to open `www.subdomain2.domain.com` or `subdomain2.domain.com`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but when I try to open the ```domain.com```, it's always the first declared ```VirtualHost``` that will be opened.

Comment: You don't have `domain.com` specified in any of your `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` directives, so the first VirtualHost will be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache will try to match the requested domain to one of the VirtualHost it knows about.  When it cannot find a match, it will use the first one it read, top to bottom in the configurations.  Hence here, your domains are not being recognized by Apache, and you get the first one all the time.

I modified your configuration a little bit:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.subdomain1.example.com
        ServerAlias subdomain1.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain1.example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub1_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub1_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.subdomain2.example.com
        ServerAlias subdomain2.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain2.example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub2_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub2_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Details:

- `NameVirtualHost` is only required if you run Apache 2.2.  >2.4, it is automatic, no need to put it, it will work anyway.
- `ServerAlias` is useful to define **another** domain name that applies to this `VirtualHost`.  If you define `ServerAlias` == `ServerName`, it is useless.
- Therefore, the `ServerAlias` are now configured with the domain names, without "www."
- Split your log files.  If you have 3 VH pointing to the same logs, it will be a real mess to debug.  It makes it easier when split.

So with this configuration...

- `http://www.subdomain1.example.com` **and** `http://subdomain1.example.com` will go to the 1st VH.
- Similar for subdomain2
- And `http://www.example.com` **and** `http://example.com` will use the third one.

This is based on your question and the comment where you say you tried `example.com`.  In your configuration, `example.com` was not listed anywhere (i.e. `www.example.com` != `example.com`).

Comment: Thank you, but in my case, I would like to have several websites, including one that points to ```www.subdomain1.example.com```, another that points to ```www.subdomain2.example.com``` and another that points to ``` www.example.com```. and this configuration <doesn't work for me 

Comment: What I proposed here does exactly that.  "does not work" is not a question, without details it is impossible for me to help further.